# 4 divs in a row, in the middle two strings are displaced

Tags: html, css

So this is actually more of a question why that is and not how I fix it. I could easily make a hack and just give the middle two strings classes that position them correctly, but I would like to know why that is and how I can properly fix it.

Heres an image to show what I mean. All 4 divs have the same code, just different images and text, still the middle two have the "XXXX players" on a different position.
[image]

Heres my html and css code:

```css
.lp-popular {
    height: 705px;
}
.lp-popular .title {
    margin-top: 91px;
    margin-left: 457px;
}
.lp-popular .game {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 240px;
    height: 383px;
    background-color: rgba(8, 9, 11, 0.5);
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.lp-popular .game .heart {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 21px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.lp-popular .game span {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.lp-popular .game p {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="lp-popular">
        <img class="title" src="img/lp_popular_header.png">
        <div align="center">
            <div class="game">
                <img src="img/lp_popular_game_lol.png">
                <img class="heart" src="img/lp_popular_heart_full.png">
                <span>League of Legends</span>
                <p>4000 Spieler</p>
            </div>
            <div class="game">
                <img src="img/lp_popular_game_dota.png">
                <img class="heart" src="img/lp_popular_heart_empty.png">
                <span>DotA 2</span>
                <p>4000 Spieler</p>
            </div>
            <div class="game">
                <img src="img/lp_popular_game_csgo.png">
                <img class="heart" src="img/lp_popular_heart_empty.png">
                <span>CS:GO</span>
                <p>4000 Spieler</p>
            </div>
            <div class="game">
                <img src="img/lp_popular_game_hs.png">
                <img class="heart" src="img/lp_popular_heart_empty.png">
                <span>Hearthstone</span>
                <p>4000 Spieler</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line of CSS to clear the floats of the game title:

```
.lp-popular .game p {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: No need to clear both. In this case clearing just left works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

why the middle images have different location for 'XXXX players': reason is pretty simple. note that first and last images have string length of 17 characters including space [League of Legends] and 10 characters [Heartstone] which fills up the the whole width available for that row. but in case of middle images, the string lenght is 6 [DOTA 2] and 5 [CS:GO] which is not enough to fill that top row. Hence the next text/string comes up to fill this gap and there-hence you get the 'XXXX players' on the same row instead of second row despite of having same css rules for them.

Fix: as @Ryan and @Akatosh have already given suggestion on how to fix this i.e.

```
.lp-popular .game p {
    clear: both;
  //  clear: left;
}
```